# e.preventDefault() not supporting in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using e.preventDefault() method it's supporting in ie9 and ie7 but in ie8 not supporting.
Please tell me how to fix this e.preventDefault() not supporting in ie8?

EDIT:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            if (!okToLeave)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: please show us your code. What is `e`? Did you use the IE specific `event`?

Comment: What you mean with "supporting"? `onbeforeunload` is not cancelable in any browser. Hmm... You've edited your question... IE7 doesn't support `e.preventDefault()` either in vanilla JS.

Comment: You have to return a string from onbeforeunload. This will output a message box containing this string for the user to confirm (or not confirm) leaving the current page

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE you can do

```
    event.returnValue = false;
```

You can test the existence of preventDefault :

```
    if (event.preventDefault)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed that in IE 9, [*returnValue*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974903(v=vs.85).aspx) does something quite different.

Answer (score 0):

[IE 8 and lower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do not support *event.preventDefault*, however setting [*event.returnValue*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to false has the same effect, though it seems to have [changed behaviour in IE 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to warn the user prior to navigating away from a page.

Perhaps that's what you want?

jQuery adds a [*preventDefault*](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to event objects as part of its event model, but only if listeners are attached using its methods.

Comment: That doesn't even attempt to answer the question. Although your constructive response sounds good in theory, its probably best to show exactly what you are talking about with some code examples.